# How to calcutate "Bonferroni Correction" for RM Anova?

Tags: anova, interpretation, post-hoc

I read all the articles, but still confusing to me. 
Bonferroni Correction = alpha .05 divided by the number of comparison.

What is exactly "comparison"?

In my Repeated Measure ANOVA case, I gave 8 subjects, and each subject had 4 measurements.

Which is correct for Bonferroni correction?

0.05 / 8 subjects = 0.00625,

or

0.05 / 4 measurements = 0.0125
?

Comment: Are you comparing persons or measurements?

Answer (score 0):

When doing multiple comparisons, the Bonferroni inequality states that the probability that if the probability of each event is less than $a$, then the probability that all $m$ events occur is less than $ma$.  So, if $a$ is $\alpha/m$, then the simultaneous occurrence of all events is less than $\alpha$. In your case, $m=8$ since you are comparing the 8 subjects with respect to a random variable that involves 4 observations (measurements).

Comment: The reasoning seams correct but the conclusion not. The topic poster does not tell what he is comparing.

Comment: I have 8 students who watched an anti-drug film. The dependent variable is attitude against drug usage. Measured twice before the film and another two times after the film.

Comment: The measurements after the film are qualitatively different than the measurements before the film.  If the film is anti drug you would expect that if the student was not against drugs before the film there would be a possibility that his opinion would change.